# Posting message on my wall facebook ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

Hello everyone i am trying to post a message on my wall but while targeting a friend. Like we post on our wall `@friendsname`.I am using the code below

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"post", @"type",
                                    urlQRCode, @"picture",
                                    [globals linktoapp], @"link",
                                    @"xsxsx", @"name",
                                    @"sxsxsxsxsx", @"caption",
                                    @"sxsxssx", @"description",
                                    messsdsage, @"message",
                                    @"friendfbuid", @"to",
                                    nil];



    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                     andParams:params1
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: You cannot post to a friend's wall [anymore](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) via the API because it has been deprecated since it generated lots of negative feedback. To tag a user in a post in your own wall you need to provide a place id as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts). Or (better way) consider implementing [actions/stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/).

Comment: Hello thanks .. i am trying to use this but its not mentioning any friends. Nsstring * message = @"message message @[fbuid:1:XXXX]";

Comment: Friends mentioning is also not possible via the Graph API in the old way as a wall post. If you, instead, use an action (maybe with 'explicit sharing' so it is currently converted into a story in the user timeline instead of a simple action) you can tag or mention friends as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions).

Answer (score 1):

```
+(SHKItem *)image:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title;


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sanFran.jpg"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Look at this picture!"];
```

read Doc And Download Shared kit Click Hare..http://getsharekit.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) postImageToFacebook {

appDelegate = (ScorecardAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

currentAPICall = kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost;

UIImage *imgSource = {insert your image here};
NSString *strMessage = @"This is the photo caption";
NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     imgSource,@"source",
                                     strMessage,@"message",
                                     nil];

[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 andParams:photosParams
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];     

// after image is posted, get URL for image and then start feed dialog
// this is done from FBRequestDelegate method
}
```

Try this. It may help you.