# Post the message to friends wall in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I used this method to post the messages 
  NSLog(@"TOKEN : %@",[[FBSession activeSession]accessTokenData]);

```
        NSMutableDictionary *birdict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Delegate.Namestring,delegate.idstring,delegate.dobstring,@"Happy Birthday", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"id",@"birthday",@"Description", nil]];


        FBRequest *request=[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",delegate.idstring]parameters:birdict HTTPMethod:@"POST"];



        NSLog(@"%@",request);

        FBRequestConnection *connection=[[FBRequestConnection alloc]init];


        [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Post Failed"
                                           message:error.localizedDescription
                                           delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
         }];
        [connection start];
    }
```

But,only last friend details is posted.I want post full friends list.Please give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"manage_friendlists", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                           completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                               /* handle success + failure in block */
                                           }];
```

source from:[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298884/posting-message-on-my-wall-facebook-ios-sdk)